# How to fetch children of node via webroot path in Gentics Mesh?

Tags: gentics-mesh

I have a webroot path of a parent node and would like to return the children of this node. 
Using https://demo.getmesh.io/api/v1/demo/webroot/images/ for example just yields the node itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to load the children of a node via REST using a single request. You can however load the node of the path. Use the uuid of that node and load the children via [/api/v1/:projectName/nodes/:nodeUuid/children](https://demo.getmesh.io/api/v1/demo/nodes/15d5ef7a9abf416d95ef7a9abf316d68/children)

A much more elegant approach however would be to use the following graphql query. I highly recommend this option since it is more efficient when handling large datasets.

*Background: Computing the `totalCount` / `totalPage` size is costly and you can avoid this by using `hasPreviousPage` and `hasNextPage`.*

You can use the following [graphql query](https://demo.getmesh.io/api/v1/demo/graphql/browser/#query=query%20(%24path%3A%20String)%20%7B%0A%20%20node(path%3A%20%24path)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20children(perPage%3A%205)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20hasNextPage%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20hasPreviousPage%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20currentPage%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20elements%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20uuid%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fields%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20vehicleImage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A&variables=%7B%0A%20%20%22path%22%3A%20%22%2Fimages%22%0A%7D%0A):

```
query ($path: String) {
  node(path: $path) {
    children(perPage: 5) {
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
      currentPage
      elements {
        uuid
        fields {
          ... on vehicleImage {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query variables:

```
{
  "path": "/images"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it's not possible to do so with just the webroot. However, there're other ways to accomplish it:

- Use the [GraphQL-Enpoint](https://getmesh.io/docs/beta/raml/#project__graphql__post) by using this query for example:

  ```
  query childrenByWebroot($path: String) {
   node(path: $path) {
     uuid
     children {
       elements {
         uuid
       }
     }
    }
  }
  ```

  This will just load all UUIDs of the children and the parent. For more functionality, check the [Docs of GraphQL](http://graphql.org/learn/) for more information.
- Load the Node from the webroot first and and then load the children via the [Children-Endpoint](https://getmesh.io/docs/beta/raml/#project__nodes__nodeUuid__children_get): `/api/v1/<project>/nodes/<uuid>/children`
- [Search for Nodes](https://getmesh.io/docs/beta/raml/#project__search_nodes_post) which have the webroot-element as parent. This allows you to filter the content more clearly if it is required:

  ```
  {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "term": {
              "parentNode.uuid": "<uuid>"
            },
            // ... Other checks
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  ```